# Route53 Subdomain not resolving my ELB

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I followed these steps :

- I created two EC2 machines hosting a single wordpress (EFS) at port 8000, the website is accessible in both machines using their ip:8000
- I created a target group for both machines (port 8000)
- I created an ELB that listens to port 80 and attached it the the target group
- I have the domain hosted in Route53 (domain.com)
- I pointed the A record of sub.domain.com to the alias of the ELB

`dig sub.domain.com` will give nothing.
I have been waiting for more than 48 hours.

Do you see any possible problem with my configuration ?

Comment: This seems typical security group issue. What are your security group configurations?

Comment: Everything is left open. The problem is in route53 because I can see this error in my browser: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: How is your alias configured? Does it have "Alias = Yes" configured in the Amazon Route 53 console? Do you have any other Route 53 entries for that domain that are working correctly?

Comment: Yes Alias is activated and yes other subdomains are configured with other domains and subdomains :)